# Link in svg not clickable in d3

Tags: d3.js, button, svg

I need to add a button in my SVG element through d3. I know you can't add Html directly to an SVG element so I use the foreign object and then add the button/the link. 
The button appears but isn't clickable and doesn't trigger any event.

I'm aware that apparently, it has something to do with the pointer-events property. But even when I try to specify "pointer-event : "none" it doesn't work.

```
var button = canvas.append("foreignObject")
.attr("class","downloadbutton")
.attr({
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : 500,
  'width': 200,
  'height': 200
})
.append("xhtml:body")

button.html("<a href='download.php' pointer-events='none' style='visibility:visible'>DL</a>");
```

I can add an href or a button, it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: your href attribute value isn't closed

Comment: Yeah, just a bug in copy paste, doesn't change anything

Comment: pointer-events none will make it not clickable because all pointer (mouse) events such as clicks will be ignored.

Comment: @RobertLongson whether I put "all" "fill" or anything it doesn't change a thing

Comment: Perhaps a [mcve] would help us diagnose your issue.